# Can't scroll enough

Tags: html, css

it's not possible to scroll enough on my page.

Here is full page on 1600x1200 resolution:
[image: Here is full page on 1600x1200 resolution]

Here is same page on resolution 1366x768:
[image: Here is same page on resolution 1366x768]

The scrollbar is fully down, and even with wheel it's not possible to scroll.

Why is that? How to solve it?
Thank you for all answers.

Comment: Just a hint, but I'd recommend keeping your CSS and JS in a separate file.

Comment: That's for tip, I will move them after end of development. :-)

Comment: Also, it's bad form to define both a `body` `id` and `class`.  Try and find a more unique name

Comment: Why is that bad?  btw I don't have body class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the complete solution for my problem is:

```
    #body
    {
        overflow: auto;

        height: 100%;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        height:auto;
        bottom:0;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        margin-top: 104px;
        margin-left: 200px;
        margin-right: 90px;
        background: #f2f4f5;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of `overflow:hidden` on the body tag. This is hiding the scroll bar that you need.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but after removing that tag, there will be two scrollbars: [see image](http://i48.tinypic.com/2dl13dj.png). I would like to have just one. How to do it?

Comment: @Peter if you remove `height:100%` from `div#body` you will only see one scrollbar.

Comment: Then there is wrong background at the bottom of page: [image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/htvph)

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure what you mean. If you hit F12 in Chrome, you can play with the styles and see which one is causing the problems though.